# location.search is not working for me as it should

Tags: javascript

When ever I output window.location.search it shows me results like this:

?x=0.8690746387001127 or any other number

but actually it should be something like

?filename=tryjsref_loc_search

Can anybody explain why it is doing this?

Here is my example code

//page url:   http://w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_host

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

document.write(window.location.search)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

output of code

?x = 0.8690746387001127

Comment: what you want? the geo location?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: His issue is that it should show the query string in the url

Comment: Out of interest, what happens when you just use location.search?

Comment: What is the address bar showing when you run that script?

Comment: i want to ask what is the relation between output  i have and the true query string

Comment: Who downvoted this? Seems like a fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're not very confortable with HTML and HTTP, and that you're learning and therefore didn't investigate the page's source code to find out what was happening.

That's perfectly okay.

Here's a simplified version of that page's source code:

```
<form id="tryitform" name="tryitform"
      action="tryit_view.asp" method="post"
      target="view"
      onsubmit="validateForm();">

    Source Code: <input type="button" value="Submit Code &raquo;"
                        onclick="submitTryit()">

    Result: <textarea id="pre_code">
        <!-- Your source code goes here -->
    </textarea>

    <input type="hidden" id="code" name="code" />
    <input type="hidden" id="bt"   name="bt"   />

    <iframe id="viewIFRAME" name="view"
            src="tryit_view.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_host">
    </iframe>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

// This Script is called when you press the "Submit Code" button
function submitTryit()
{
    // I'll omit the code, but what it does is this:

    // 1. Take the text (your code) in the 'pre_code' textarea
    // and substitute '=' with 'w3equalsign'
    // and 'script' with 'w3scrw3ipttag'.

    // 2. Put the modified text in the 'code' hidden input field

    // 3. Change the form's action to "tryit_view.asp?x=" + a random number

    // 4. Call validateForm(), which basically
    // only checks if the code doesn't exceed 5000 characters

    // 5. Submit form
}

window.onload = function(){ submitTryit() }
// Call submitTryit() when the page first loads
// so the view is filled also when you first arrive.

</script>
```

The key idea to understand here is that the code you write goes on a form where the `action` attribute is set to "tryit_view.asp?x=" + a random number, and the `target` attribute is set to "view". This `target` attribute on the form means the result of the form's submission should appear on the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) which as the attribute `name` set to "view".

So you see, the problem is that your code isn't actually being run on the page you're seeing on the browser. It is in fact being sent in a POST to the server.
The server then responds with a different page which goes to fill the contents of the iframe.

An iframe is basically a "mini-browser in a rectangle" that appears nested inside the main page, and it has a different URL which has nothing to do with your main page's URL and does not appear on the address bar. This URL is instead the URL of the form's action.

Now presumably what the server does in response to the POST is simply create an HTML page with the code you submitted, after reverting those weird text substitutions above.
And so your code ends up running inside the iframe.

So, when you write `window.location` or just `location`, your code will end up actually accessing the iframe's location and not your main page's location.

You can access the parent page's location like this:

```
// 'parent', same as 'window.parent', refers to
// the frame which is the parent of the frame where
// this code is being run (the iframe named 'view').
document.write( parent.location.search );
```

Or like this:

```
// "top" is the frame at the top of the frame hierarchy
document.write( top.location.search );
```

Good luck on your learning!

Comment: thankx dude,,,it's what realy true thing happening behind the scene,,,

Comment: I've edited the answer slightly, mostly because I had written the wrong URL for the POST, but also for re-wording and explaining some parts better (I hope). But yeah, this is what's happening behind the scenes. If you have Firebug installed, or some other development tool that allows you to see your HTTP traffic, you can see the POST being made and the answer the server gives you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [w3schools is not a good website to learn from](http://w3fools.com/). I'd recommend [jqFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics) instead (the "javascript basics" section)

That being said, the [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) gives you the current querystring of the window. In the case of w3school's "Try It" site, this appears to be a `Math.rand()` which is usually used as a [cachebuster](http://manikandanc.blogspot.com/2005/11/cache-busting-with-javascript.html) technique.

If you have fiddler (or any other network traffic monitor) running when you click the "submit" button, you'll see the full URL is `http://w3schools.com/jsref/tryit_view.asp?x=0.42147885356098413`.

MDN is a great source of javascript documentation, their entry on [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) says:

> search | the part of the URL that follows the ? symbol, including the ? symbol. | ?q=devmo

Comment: thankx for suggestions i'll follow,,,,,can i convert x=0.42147885356098413 back to actual which was shown to me?if yes then why

Comment: you introduced me to many new things,thankx again thumbs up,,,,

Comment: i have got true thing about x=003403242304,iframes are working here out,,,,